# How to configure hello-slick-3.0 app for mysql (async)

Tags: scala, slick

I'm trying to update the hello-slick-3.0 application downloaded using typesafe activator to use mysql rather than the h2 in-mem database. I've changed all the references to h2 to import import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._, but I don't know how to force the correct version of this driver at runtime. I'm getting this error at runtime:

background log: info: Running HelloSlick 
background log: error: Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

I wish to start using the async mysql driver with scala/slick.

Comment: I'm assuming I don't want to be using mysql-connector-java, since it is not async. What driver do I use, and where do I find it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use standard MySQL JDBC driver, for example:

```
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.35"
```

Slick 3 implements "asynchrony" itself using Reactive Streams.

Comment: Doesn't the standard MySQL JDBC driver block? Isn't some other mysql driver, such as this one: https://github.com/mauricio/postgresql-async needed?

Comment: Yes, it does. But Slick uses reactive streams to make it asynchronous "in a best way". It's not completely asynchronous as you think. It's hard to prove, I couldn't find any explicit statements, but you can take a look here:

1) https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/44#issuecomment-62552857
2)  http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0-RC3/introduction.html#reactive-applications
3) and a code base :) 

I use blocking Postgres driver - works like a charm